# Testing specific categories after Fisher's exact test in 2 x k tables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, nonparametric, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

I have two variables, one with 2 categories and one with 6 categories.
To test, whether there is any relation between these variables, I performed
Fisher's exact test, which gave a significant result.

Now I want to know for which of the categories of the second variable respective 
subjects have a differing distribution of the first variable (the one with 2 
categories) with respect to subjects not in this specific category of the 
second variable.

For this purpose I wanted to do the following:
For each category c of the second variable (c in {1,...,6}):
Group all subjects belonging to category c together and all
subjects not belonging to category c, which results in a
new binary variable variable2_c.
Perform Fisher's exact test between variable2_c and the first variable (the
one with 2 categories).

Do you think this procedure is justified or do you see any problems with
this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thank you in advance!